How to sort worksheets by name in a PhpSpreadsheet workbook without disrupting sheet indices?
I'm currently working with PhpSpreadsheet to generate evaluation reports in .xlsx format. These evaluations are categorized (e.g., Evaluation A, Evaluation B, etc.), and I need to group all similar types together.
My application features functionality that merges all types of evaluations into a single worksheet within a workbook. I temporarily store each type of evaluation on the server in a well-organized folder in my storage, which has proper read and write permissions.
Once all these evaluations are stored, I iterate over each worksheet and sheet to consolidate the data into a single "MasterSpreadsheet." Up to this point, everything works as expected.
However, I'm facing an issue where I need to sort these evaluations by their sheet names in the final workbook. Unfortunately, PhpSpreadsheet does not provide built-in functionality for this, and my current workaround—to clone the MasterSpreadsheet and insert sheets in alphabetical order—is causing confusion due to sheet index discrepancies.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or have a solution that could help sort the sheets alphabetically without messing up the sheet indices? Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
foreach ($sheetNames as $name) {
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName($name);
    if (!$sheet) {
        error_log("Sheet $name doesn't exist in this workbook.");
        continue;
    }
    $clonedSheet = clone $sheet;
    $clonedSheet->setTitle($name);
    $newSpreadsheet->addSheet($clonedSheet);
}
}

So far i did this to reinsert in a new Spreadsheet all the sheets sorted. But i have always the error message
Undefined array key 2

Help...

PhpSpreadsheet Version : 1.18
Php 8.1
Laravel 8.75


Try below approach that extracts all sheet names, sorting them, and then cloning each sheet. These cloned sheets are stored temporarily in an array. After all sheets are cloned, they are added sequentially to a new spreadsheet. This method avoids direct index manipulation during the cloning process, thereby preventing the 'Undefined array key' error by ensuring that operations related to sheet indexing are managed separately and more cleanly.
$sheetNames = [];
foreach ($spreadsheet->getSheetNames() as $sheetName) {
    $sheetNames[] = $sheetName;
}
sort($sheetNames);  // Sort sheet names alphabetically
$newSpreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
$clonedSheets = [];

foreach ($sheetNames as $sheetName) {
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName($sheetName);
    if (!$sheet) {
        error_log("Sheet $sheetName doesn't exist in this workbook.");
        continue;
    }
    $clonedSheet = clone $sheet;
    $clonedSheet->setTitle($sheetName);
    $clonedSheets[] = $clonedSheet;  // Collect cloned sheets
}

// Now add cloned sheets to the new spreadsheet
foreach ($clonedSheets as $index => $clonedSheet) {
    if ($index === 0) {
        // Set the first sheet in the new spreadsheet
        $newSpreadsheet->removeSheetByIndex(0); // Remove default sheet
        $newSpreadsheet->addSheet($clonedSheet, 0);
    } else {
        $newSpreadsheet->addSheet($clonedSheet);
    }
}


Thanks for the quick response. Despite minimizing index manipulation, the error persists at the same index every time. After ensuring all sheets are correctly added to $newSpreadsheet, the error occurs during the $writer->save($newSpreadsheet, 'Xlsx'); operation:
This operation is executed after my $newSpreadsheet has been fully populated:
$fileName1 = 'AllEvaluationsABC_.xlsx'; $filePath1 = storage_path('temp/' . $fileName1); $writer1 = IOFactory::createWriter($newSpreadsheet, 'Xlsx'); $writer1->save($filePath1);
Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue?
